# Calculating compound interest with subsequest payments

Tags: php, math, finance

I would like to calculate future balance of an investment with periodic deposits (monthly, weekly etc.)

I created the simple php script for that, but the results differs from those presented in many online calculators. Each of them returns similar results, so the problem must be with my script.

```
<?php 

$future_balance = 0;
$interest = 0.08;
$monthly_deposit = 1000;
for (var $i=0; $i<20*12; $i++) {
    $future_balance = $future_balance * (1+$interest/12) + $monthly_deposit;
}
```

I also do not know how to implement different compounding periods. Should I made another loop inside loop or what?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for using a loop for such calculation. You can use a enchaned version of formula for compound interest.

Depending on your needs you can use one of two variants.

**1) Deposits at the end of compounding period**

FV = PMT * (((1 + r/n)^(n*t) - 1) / (r/n))

**2) Deposits at the begining of compounding period**

FV = PMT * (((1 + r/n)^(n*t) - 1) / (r/n)) * (1 + r/n)

Legend:

- FV = the future value
- PMT = value of your regular payment
- r = the
  annual interest rate (decimal number)
- n = compounding frequency (per
  year)
- t = lenght of the investment in years (for 1 month you can
  substitute 1/12)

After you implement this formula you can validate your results here https://calcopolis.com/saving/saving